# No reconoce los botones de un dialogo personalizado Error NullPointerException Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, xml, onclicklistener

Tengo una activity llamada "Juego1Niv1" con su respectivo xml.
Tengo además de eso otro xml llamado "dialogogameover1" el cual implementaré para llamarlo como un dialogo desde un metodo de la actividad "Juego1Niv1".

He querido implementar el uso de un dialogo personalizado "dialogogameover1" en una activity individual "Juego1Niv1". El dialogo que creé contiene dos botones en su xml, de los cuales programo sus eventos con OnClickListener dentro de mi metodo "gameover" en "Juego1Niv1".

el objetivo es que al ejecutarse el metodo "gameover" salga el dialogo y al pulsar alguno de los botones de ese dialogo me envíe con intent a otra activiy.

Creo entender mas o menos que el error que me da el Debug es porque algo está vacio (desde el xml del dialogo al codigo java) o su conexión no la está tomando en cuenta. Pero no se como darle solucion.

Este es mi codigo:

```
public void gameover(){
    
    if(gameover==true){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Juego1niv1Atv.this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogogameover1, null);
        builder.setView(view); builder.setCancelable(false);
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create(); dialog.show();
        
        //conecto el textview del xml del dialogo a la parte logica de java
        TextView txtdpuntaje = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_d_show_score);
        txtdpuntaje.setText(""+(score));

        //conecto los botones del xml del dialogo a la parte logica java
        btn_signivel1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_sig1);
        btn_relent1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_relent1);

        //Boton ir a siguiente nivel
        btn_signivel1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 Intent i = new Intent(this, MenuJugarActivity.class);
                 startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        //boton bajar velocidad
        btn_relent1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    relen=true;
                    paso();
            }
        });
        
    }
}
```

El Debug me dice esto:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

Que deberia hacer en este caso? porque al compilar ni siquiera me muestra el dialogo personalizado, me gustaria interactuar con los botones de ese dialogo pero dentro del archivo java.

**Resumen del problema:** El archivo java ya tiene su xml por aparte, y al llamar el dialogo de otro xml no logro interactuar con sus botones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te he entendido correctamente, estos botones

```
//conecto los botones del xml del dialogo a la parte logica java
btn_signivel1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_sig1);
btn_relent1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_relent1);
```

están dentro del dialog, no??
Entonces deberás buscarlos en el diálogo, si usas `findViewById()` estarás buscándolos en el XML de tu activity actual, no en el XML del diálogo. Para ello debes usar

```
view.findViewById(R.id.btn_sig1);
view.findViewById(R.id.btn_relent1);
```

ya que en `view` tienes guardada la View del diálogo, es decir, su XML inflado.